# Removing index.php is not SEO friendly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

Writing htaccess that allows me to remove index.php from the URL can confuse search engines because i will have many links that leads to the same page e.g.

http://www.domain.com/index.php/welcome/index
http://www.domain.com/index.php/welcome/
http://www.domain.com/welcome/index
http://www.domain.com/welcome/

As you see, when it comes to SEO, this could be a problem. What can i do to solve this problem?

My .htaccess include the following commands:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci_sample/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Choose one of the urls and let all the others permanently redirect to it.

Comment: You don't have multiple links, you only have multiple ways of accessing the page. If you stick to one method when placing links on your site, it's not a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should set 301 redirect from all that URLs to one, chosen by you as a main one.
2. You can add rel=canonical tag on your main page and put the chosen URL there, to inform crawler about proper site address.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're linking to all possible combinations of each individual URI, then the search engines will be none the wiser to the variety of addresses pointing to the same resource. They're only going to crawl visible links on your site, so decide on a convention and go with it. If you never link to `index.php/welcome/index` on any page of your site, chances are it will never be indexed that way.

Answer (score 0):

This will surely work...    I have used this code to remove index.php and its working well for me. There is no problem in the SEO by this code.

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```